# Расширить с помощью ImageDataGenerator количество изображений

Tags: python, нейронные-сети, keras, tensorflow

Как правильно расширить количество изображений с помощью ImageDataGenerator

```
    datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255,
                            rotation_range=90,
                            horizontal_flip=True,
                            vertical_flip=True,
                            fill_mode='reflect')
train_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='categorical')
```

Вот тут я не пойму что нужно добавить?
Вроде все по инструкции но количество изображений не увеличивается?

Comment: Новые Изображения на диске не появятся. Просто у НС будет больше обучающая выборка во время обучения

Comment: а как он определяет насколько больше?